# Using ASP sessionID/Cookie to secure login site

Tags: security, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a Classic ASP website that need a a bit of beefing up on security.

What I figured  is building a table, that consists of the following field:

```
SessionID (the 9 digit ASP sessionID)
Time Logged in
IP they logged in at
userID  (the user's ID in the database)
```

When the user logs in, i save the `sessionID`, in the DB, along with the time, IP and the userID. This logon is only valid for 6 hours (for example) -  and when i see that 6 hrs have pass beyond the `time logged in` field - i make the user log in again. 
Similarly, if i pickup that the IP address has changed - I make him login again.
All of this is possible, because i am using the ASP `session.sessionID` to compare with in the login table described above.

Is this a good method - or is it still better to use a cookie, for the `sessionID`? Anything else that should be done better?

Thanks

Comment: Some [good advice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972338.aspx?f=255) about session management in Classic ASP. Also worth reading the [remarks section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524326(v=vs.90).aspx) of `Session.SessionID`.

Comment: Thanks! That first link didnt seem to load - can you verify?
and regarding the 2nd link: i hear that. Its possible that the server will restart with the 6 hours, and then someone will get the same sessionID - though chances are low it will be from the same IP address. Still best to be full proof. Would it be better to generate my own unique long code, rather than using the sessionID?

Comment: sorry, should have been [ASP and Web Session Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972338.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Just edited my previous comment ^^